# Error Process finished with exit code 0. starter-web and starter-tomcat does not help. intellij does not accept data from the bot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I created a spring maven telegram bot.
I got the error `Process finished with exit code 0` 
I added the `@Component`  annotation, but the problem persisted.
I added it to the pom file:

```
<dependency
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This helped to get rid of the problem, but the bot does not accept data from the telegram chat.
I write to chat \start, but the console does not display anything.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoAf9.png)

console output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGtxq.png)
Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>Najavnist</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-bot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>java-bot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.telegram/telegrambots-spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${parent.version}</version><!-- щоб виправити-->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;

@Component//вкажи цю анотацію
public class JavaBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "bot";
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return "uwu";
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
System.out.println(update.getMessage());//вся інфа

    }
}
```

```
package Najavnist.java.bot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JavaBotApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JavaBotApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }

}
```

Comment: in this code, of course, I replaced the real token and name

Comment: I would also be grateful if you could explain how to create a file in the resources so that the token and name are stored there

Comment: I changed the version and everything worked. why is that?


```<version>2.7.12</version>
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as [properly formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).